# About Rees homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, congruences, semigroups

I am came across the  notion `Rees Congruence` for semigroups. J. Howie defines it as $$\rho_I=(I\times I)\cup {1_S}$$ wherein $I$ is an ideal of semigroup $S$ satisfying a certain property. Then, we turn to `Rees Homomorphism` as a homomorphism $\phi: S\to T$ where $\text{ker}{\phi}$ is a Rees congruence. I am puzzled about how such that kernel could be treated as $\rho_I$ for some ideals $I$ of $S$.

In fact, what would that ideal be taken? Of course, I know that the kernel is a congruence on $S$ and every congruence can be a kernel of a semigroups homomorphism. Thanks for making me some light.

Comment: Could you possibly make your question more explicit, I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: @JamesMitchell: Dear James, sorry for bringing up the question inappropriately. I meant "How can that kernel be a Ress con.?" Indeed, $\text{ker}{\phi}$ is a con. on $S$ and if it wanted to be a Ress con. we need an Idwal such that $\text{ker}{\phi}=(I\times I)\cup \Delta_{S}$. I am asking about this possible $I$. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ideal is part of the definition: a homomorphism $\phi$ is a Rees homomorphism if the kernel of the homomorphism is a Rees congruence, i.e. if $\operatorname{ker}(\phi)=(I\times I)\cup \Delta_S$ for some ideal $I$ of $S$.

So, if you are given a Rees homomorphism it comes with an ideal in the definition. If you are given a homomorphism and want to show it is a Rees homomorphism, you must show that the kernel is a Rees congruence by showing that it has at most one non-singleton kernel class and that the elements of that class form an ideal of $S$.

Comment: That you say `...non-singleton kernel class...` is the same fact that `S is simple iff it consists of a single J-class` ? Or I misunderstand the point? Thanks James for the time.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking. The kernel of a homomorphism is an equivalence relation, hence the equivalence classes of a kernel partition the semigroup $S$. If the size of a kernel class equals 1, it is called a singleton class. For a homomorphism to be a Rees homomorphism, its kernel must have at most one class with more than one element, and the set of elements in the class must be an ideal in $S$.

Comment: @James : Please tell the examples of Rees homomorphism